# Electron error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND after View Reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I ran into a  strange bug that I'm not sure how to fix. I'm using Angular 17 and Electron 28.

Here is my configuration:

```
win.loadFile(
  path.join(__dirname, "/dist/angular-electron/browser/index.html")
);
```

I also tried:

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/angular-electron/browser/index.html`);
// the same issue.
```

Here is the script I use to run Electron:

```
 "electron": "electron ."
```

I do have base href in my HTML:

```
<base href="./" />
```

When I run the script, everything is fine and loaded as expected, no errors. Now, when I go to `"View"` and click `"Reload"`, I get this error:

```
(node:38812) electron: Failed to load URL: file:///C:/somepath/Electron/angular-electron-my/dist/angular-electron/browser/ with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
(Use `electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

By looking at the error, I also don't see `/index.html` at the end. Not sure if it's supposed to be this way or not.

What doesn't make sense to me is that it initially  loads as expected  and throws this error when I `"Reload"` in electron's View.

I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

It is somehow related to Angular 17. The issue was not reproducible  while using Angular 16.

Also, after doing a lot of testing I was able to figure out how to fix it. After looking at the **index.html** after the build step, I had 2 scripts in it :

```
<script src="polyfills-LZBJRJJE.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-LB5VRZFU.js" type="module"></script>
```

After removing `"type=module"` the reported issue was resolved. Not sure why that is happening and will probably create a bug report.